In MAUI Is There Any Ways To Opne Window In Minimized State
var chartWindow = new ChartWindowPage();
var window = new Window(chartWindow);
Application.Current?.OpenWindow(window);

This is sample code to open a window it by default opened Maximized State or Normal State
In above code I'm expecting it should opened in minimized state

You can use the code below to minimize the new opened window:
async void MinimizeWindow()
{

        await Task.Delay(10);
#if WINDOWS
        var window = GetParentWindow().Handler.PlatformView as MauiWinUIWindow;

        var appWindow = GetAppWindow(window);

        switch (appWindow.Presenter)
        {
            case Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter overlappedPresenter:
                overlappedPresenter.Minimize();
                break;
         }
#endif
}

#if WINDOWS
private Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow GetAppWindow(MauiWinUIWindow window)
{
        var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
        var id = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
        var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);
        return appWindow;
}
#endif


